# Please help to execute my .xprofile script

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Hi I am trying to adjust the screen size of my HDMI connected TV using xrandr commands. I execute a series of commands to adjust screen size one after the other from terminal. All the commands are working fine and it solves my problem but as soon as I log out or close the session, the screen size problem returns when I log in next.

I had read somewhere that it is better to keep all the commands as script in .xprofile file so that the commands get automatically executed everytime the system boots up or the user logs in. I did that by storing all commands as a script in .xprofile file but it did not work. I have doubts on why the script is not getting executed when I log in. Probably I am not keeping the script at right place.Currently I am keeping it in my home directory /home/dheeraj but it is not getting executed automatically. Manually if I run the script it works.

Please help me to run the .xprofile script automatically so that when I log in it runs.

I am new to Linux so I may have missed some details. Please feel free to ask.
I am running MX Linux( I didn't know where to ask so I am asking here)
Following is the script saved as .xprofile:

> xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.0 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083
>   1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
>
> xrandr -addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
>
> xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
>
> xrandr --output HDMI-1 --transform 1.05 , 0 , -35,0,1.05 ,-30 ,0,0,1

Thanks

Comment: You don't say how your X session is started, but have a look here, as this may help you out. Make sure your .xprofile is executable (chmod +x .xprofile) [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile)

Answer (score 0):

If bash is your default shell, you could place those commands in ~/.bashrc

If zsh, it would be ~./zshrc

Those should be run at login

EDIT:

See if you have 'System > Preferences > Sessions' available.

If you do, you can add "apps" (including scripts like yours) with 'Add' there. Items in that list should be run at desktop login. I can install MX in a VM if more info is needed or above options aren't available.

Comment: I had put the commands in .bashrc . It worked only when I opened a terminal. What I want is that the system should execute those commands when the user logs in and not when he opens a terminal.